# How do I convert Hinglish and Hindi words or sentences to English using python?

Tags: python, unicode, jupyter-notebook, translation, data-cleaning

I have been facing the following issues.

- The code which was scraping tweets has yet again stopped working.
- The previously scraped tweets have some rows which contain different languages but in the Unicode format. I have tried to convert them multiple times but have been unable to. I will give an example below.

e.g.: `"  - 400 à¤°à¥à¤ªà¤¯à¥‡ à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ à¤à¤• à¤ªà¥à¤²à¥‡à¤Ÿ maggi, à¤²à¥‹à¤—à¥‹à¤‚ à¤•à¥‡ à¤‰à¤¡à¤¼ à¤—à¤ à¤¹à¥‹à¤¶"`

or - `"hey tastiest à¤¨à¤° à¤°à¤•à¤«à¤¸à¤Ÿ à¤°à¤š à¤¹ à¤¯ à¤š à¤¹ à¤¸à¤¥ à¤® 1 à¤¹ cc"`

- There are 'Hinglish' words and sentences, and I can't translate those as well.
  E.g.:

```
"ye to kuch nahi, do you remember the free cars you get with bournvita which had a winder too to accelerate those cars ðŸ˜"
or
"kis cheez se khelte hai?
ho skta mere ghr pe kuchh aur bolte ho use"
```

I have been trying to convert both to English but failing miserably. There are multiple rows in my data. I request any help possible.

Thank you for your time.

I tried different libraries, which said that they would convert it properly.
And I expected it to turn into proper English sentences.

Comment: Can you give an example of a translation library you've tried, and what problems you ran into with it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share a code snippet where you are scrapping tweets… BTW, you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: ```"hey tastiest à¤¨à¤° à¤°à¤•à¤«à¤¸à¤Ÿ à¤°à¤š à¤¹ à¤¯ à¤š à¤¹ à¤¸à¤¥ à¤® 1 à¤¹ cc".encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')``` returns ```'hey tastiest नर रकफसट रच ह य च ह सथ म 1 ह cc'```.